# Elasticsearch: What if size of index is larger than available RAM?

Tags: elasticsearch

Assuming a single machine system with an in-memory indexing schema.

I am not able to find this info in ES docs. Does ES start swapping out the overflowing data, loads it when needed and continue working or it gives an error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In-memory indices provide better performance at the cost of limiting the index size to the amount of available physical memory.

Via the [1.7 documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.7/index-modules-store.html). Memory stores are no longer available in 2.0+.

Under the hood it uses the Lucene RAMDirectory, which will just consume RAM (and eventually swap) until either you hit Java heap limits and ES crashes with out-of-memory errors, or the system gives up and oomkills the Elasticsearch process. Don't use in-memory indexes for large indexes, or for any situation where persistence is important.

Comment: https://lucene.apache.org/core/4_1_0/core/org/apache/lucene/store/RAMDirectory.html - it's just a Java class that allocates 1024-byte buffers from the Java heap to store index data. Standard Java heap usage caveats apply.